# Percorrer diretórios com recursiva no JAVA

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade sobre como percorrer diretórios com recursiva em java e até agora tenho este código aqui:

```
    package Control;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

public class PercorreDir {

    private String pastas = "";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    public String percorre(String caminho, String espaço){

        File documentos = new File(caminho);

        for( File files : documentos.listFiles()){
            if(files.isDirectory()) {

                buffer.append(files + espaço);
                percorre(caminho, espaço);
            }
        }

        return pastas;

    }
}
```

O que eu quero saber é como faço para o método percorrer também as subpastas. Obrigado.

Comment: O método acima já faz o que você falou. Esta pergunta não faz sentido. Além disso, por favor, evite criar várias perguntas para o mesmo problema. Se a resposta da primeira pergunta não resolveu, melhore a pergunta editando-a e adicionando informações relevantes. Você também pode adicionar comentários nas respostas dizendo o motivo delas não resolverem o problema.

Comment: Esta pergunta já tem uma resposta aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101904/exibir-diret%C3%B3rios-em-formato-de-arvore e também aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101772/recursiva-em-java-para-ver-pastas-e-subpastas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, encontrei um código que poderá ser didático para o seu aprendizado em questão de recursividade.
O código abaixo serve para procurar um arquivo e ele busca em todas as pastas/subpasatas.

```
   package com.mkyong;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ProcurarArquivo {

      private String nomeParaBuscar;
      private List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();

      public String getNomeDoArquivoParaBuscar() {
        return nomeParaBuscar;
      }

      public void setNomeDoArquivoParaBuscar(String nomeParaBuscar) {
        this.nomeParaBuscar = nomeParaBuscar;
      }

      public List<String> getResultado() {
        return resultado;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcurarArquivo procurarArquivo = new ProcurarArquivo();

        //tente diferentes diretorios.
        procurarArquivo.procurarPasta(new File("/var/www/html"), "post.php");

        int count = procurarArquivo.getResultado().size();
        if(count ==0){
            System.out.println("\nNão foi encontrado!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\nencontrado " + count + " resultados!\n");
            for (String bateu : procurarArquivo.getResultado()){
            System.out.println("encontrado : " + bateu);
            }
        }
      }

      public void procurarPasta(File diretorio, String nomeParaBuscar) {

        setNomeDoArquivoParaBuscar(nomeParaBuscar);

        if (diretorio.isDirectory()) {
            procurar(diretorio);
        } else {
            System.out.println(diretorio.getAbsoluteFile() + " não é um diretório!");
        }

      }

      private void procurar(File arquivo) {

        if (arquivo.isDirectory()) {
          System.out.println("procurando pasta ... " + arquivo.getAbsoluteFile());

            //você tem permissão para ler?
            if (arquivo.canRead()) {
            for (File temp : arquivo.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                procurar(temp);
                } else {
                if (getNomeDoArquivoParaBuscar().equals(temp.getName().toLowerCase())) {            
                    resultado.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                }

            }
            }

         } else {
            System.out.println(arquivo.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permissão negada");
         }
          }

      }

    }
```