# StackOverflowError em método recursivo ao percorrer pastas e subpastas

Tags: java, recursão

Este método recursivo:

```
public static void percorre(File caminho, String espaço){

    if(caminho.isDirectory()){
        for (int cta = 1; cta <= nespaço; cta++){
            buffer.append(espaço);
        }

        buffer.append(caminho.getName() + "\n");
        nespaço += 1;
        percorre(caminho, espaço);

    } else if (caminho.isDirectory() != true){
        nespaço = 0;
    }

}
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está a acontecer?

Obs: Linha 14 é o If e a 21 é a chamada da recursiva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu método recursivo `percorre()` está sendo chamado sempre com os mesmos parâmetros. Isso está fazendo estourar a pilha de execução (as chamadas sucessivas se empilharam e excederam a máxima quantidade permitida).

Imagino que você queira percorrer as subpastas. Para isso deve trocar essa linha:

```
percorre(caminho, espaço);
```

por esse trecho:

```
for (File subpasta: caminho.listFiles()) {
   percorre(subspasta, espaço);
}
```

Não sei se isso por si só resolve o problema porque não compreendi totalmente a sua lógica. Não sei o que fazem as variáveis `espaço` e `nespaço`. Mas o caminho para fazer o código funcionar é esse.

(Nota: Esse trecho `else if (caminho.isDirectory() != true)` pode ser substituído por um simples `else`).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente funcionou. Era isso mesmo!!