# Exibir diretórios em formato de arvore

Tags: java

tenho este código aqui em JAVA em que preciso listas as pastas e subpastas em formato de árvore, mas eu não to conseguindo. Alguma ajuda?

```
package Control;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PercorreDir {


    public static StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    public static int nespaço = 1;
    public static String espaço = "";

    public static StringBuffer percorre(File caminho){

        if(caminho.isDirectory()){

            buffer.append(espaço + caminho.getName()+"\n");

            for (File subpasta: caminho.listFiles()) {          

                for (int cta = 0; cta < nespaço; cta++){
                    espaço += "    ";
                }

                nespaço += 1;

                percorre(subpasta);
                }
        } else {
            nespaço = 0;
            espaço = "    ";

        }

        return buffer;

    }
}
```

Comment: Seu problema é nos espaços, certo? Pelo código acima eles devem estar "descontrolados"... (se for outra coisa, favor esclarecer, estou escrevendo uma resposta abordando isso)

Comment: Sim, são os espaços. Vou editar e colocar uma foto de como sai a saída

Comment: Não precisa, consigo imaginar... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se problema é que sempre que você encontra um arquivo você "reseta" o número de espaços pra zero, o que faz com que a próxima pasta na fila seja impressa como se estivesse na raiz. Não é necessário fazer nada de especial no caso de arquivos (já que você não quer tratá-los), em vez disso sugiro incrementar o número de espaços antes de percorrer a subpasta, e ao final decrementar de novo. Ou melhor ainda, não use uma variável global (estática), e sim passe o prefixo de cada pasta como parâmetro:

```
public static StringBuffer percorre(File caminho){
    return percorre(caminho, "");
}

public static StringBuffer percorre(File caminho, String prefixo){

    if(caminho.isDirectory()){

        buffer.append(prefixo + caminho.getName()+"\n");

        String novoPrefixo = prefixo + "    ";

        for (File subpasta: caminho.listFiles()) {          
            percorre(subpasta, novoPrefixo);
        }
    }

    return buffer;

}
```

Comment: Nota: essa resposta assume que as pastas da raiz começam sem espaço algum no começo. Se você quer que elas também tenham 4 espaços antes, basta mudar a condição inicial para `return percorre(caminho, "    ");`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas e se eu quisesse listar os arquivos que estão na subpasta? Como eu faria?

Comment: Bom, você pode colocar um `else { buffer.append(prefixo + caminho.getName()+"\n") }`, ou simplesmente fazer essa operação antes do `if` (já que é igual tanto pra pastas quanto pra arquivos). Mas se você quiser diferenciá-los de alguma forma - por exemplo colocando `[P] ` ou `[A] ` na frente antes de imprimí-lo - então é melhor fazer no `else` mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado cara! Salvou meu semestre haha